# Loading non embedded views from other projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, virtualpathprovider, griffin.mvccontrib

I'm working on a mvc3 project which should support modules. So for example I have a MVC3 core project and a MVC3 module project (MyModule).

Now I wish to load and display the views from the MVC3 module project in the core project.
I wrote a custom VirtualPathProvider class and a VirtualFile class which fetches the views from other locations than the core project.

Somehow I get the following error: `CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context.`

What I'm doing is loading the assembly from the module project in my core project using the following line of code in the AssemblyInfo class in the core project:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ModuleLoader), "Init")]
```

The ModuleLoader class fetches the DLL and uses `BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly` to add the assembly.

Now I can call action methods in MyModuleController.cs by navigating to `http://localhost/MyModule`. In the Index ActionResult method of MyModuleController.cs I return the View like this:

```
return View("~/Modules/MyModule/Index.cshtml");
```

The VirtualPathProvider checks if the path starts with ~/Modules/ and fetches the view (MyModule -> Views -> Index.cshtml) from the module project.

Now I've searched for the error and I read about missing Web.config files, but I have everything in the module project, because it's a complete MVC3 web project.

I read a lot about loading **embedded** views from assemblies, but is what I described above even possible?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Decided to go the Griffin-MvcContrib way and use its plugin system, which seems to provide everything I need and on top of that it uses Autofac, which I already decided to use for IOC!

[Griffin.MvcContrib - The plugin system](http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-mvccontrib-the-plugin-system/)

Comment: Can you add a proper answer to this? Otherwise it may be closed as too localized. @jgauffin If you'd like to summarize an answer to this, nothing wrong with that (encourage you to do so, in fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom `VirtualPathProvider` and adding an reference to the `BuildManager` is just part of the solution. You also need to modify the views and specify which layout to use for every view in the DLLs.

Next you also have to use `@inherits` instead of `@model` the views.

Or you can simply use Griffin.MvcContrib which takes care of everything for you: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-mvccontrib-the-plugin-system/